# How to over come error on RMAN

Tags: oracle, rman

I am getting following error in RMAN:-

```
Starting backup at 18-NOV-15
using channel ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile copy
input datafile file number=00001 name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 11/18/2015 14:19:36
ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server
continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile copy
input datafile file number=00002 name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/sysaux01.dbf
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 11/18/2015 14:19:37
ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server
continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile copy
input datafile file number=00003 name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/undotbs01.dbf
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 11/18/2015 14:19:38
ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle server
continuing other job steps, job failed will not be re-run
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile copy
input datafile file number=00004 name=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/users01.dbf
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 11/18/2015 14:19:40
RMAN-03015: error occurred in stored script Memory Script
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 11/18/2015 14:19:39
ORA-17628: Oracle error 19505 returned by remote Oracle
```

Comment: provide clear description of the question, and what have you tried

Comment: i was trying to do dataguard setup, but when i am trying to create stndby database using command "rman target sys/Password@orcl auxiliary sys/password@orcl_stby"  then i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-19505: failed to identify file <file>` means there is some missing file.

First, do a `crosscheck` with RMAN. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. RMAN-03009 & ORA-17628
   You will see this error when A previous duplicate had been done to this same location and some of the datafiles still remained in place.

   Solution: Remove the named files from the "AUXILIARY server" and retry the duplicate
2. ORA-19505
   You will see this error when db_file_name_convert not specified and controlfile location is wrong. Please specify the correct path.